# Mysql2::Error: # MySQL client is not connected — Rails 6.0.2.2 with rspec; Ruby 2.6.4 mac os Catalina + Mojave

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm getting this extremely strange intermittent problem with MySQL on Rails 6.0.2.2, 
RSpec 4.0.0.rc1,
Ruby 2.6.4

on a two separate Macs, one is running macOS Mojave and the other is running MacOS Catalina

Interestingly, the mac running Catalina appears to do it less often, although it still does this. the failure is intermittent, seems to happen immediately after another failure in the suite, but then often continues to show up (across about half of the test suite) on subsequent runs, even if I've fixed the originally failing spec.

```
  1) Template 
     Failure/Error: _query(sql, @query_options.merge(options))

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Mysql2::Error: MySQL client is not connected
     # /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `_query'
     # /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `block in query'
     # /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:130:in `handle_interrupt'
     # /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:130:in `query'
     # /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/rspec-wait-0.0.9/lib/rspec/wait.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Mysql2::Error:
     #   MySQL client is not connected
     #   /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.4/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131:in `_query'
```

Comment: Have you read [mre]? Including only the output of the spec is not helpful.

Comment: Race conditions only happen on larger, complex apps. "minimum" app don't show these kinds of race conditions. However, I will try to reproduce this in a stand-along app that I can push to github

Comment: That’s the point I’m trying to make: if it requires a big and complex app to reproduce then how can you expect anyone to reproduce it off the vague description you gave? We can’t. That’s why you need to put in the work to make it reproducible, otherwise no one can help.

Comment: generally I would agree with you in all contexts *except* race conditions. If you boot my app on your machine, any number of factors could mean that you won't be able to reproduce the problem (most often, the relative speed of our laptop processors). In this case, it was race conditions (but I didn't actually know that before I posted this… now I do)

Answer (score 10):

I began having this problem when I set up my personal laptop (Mac OS Catalina) to do work from home. In the process, I updated our environment from Ruby 2.4.7 to 2.6.3 and gems system from 3.0.6 to 3.1.2. And, no doubt, incremental updates to our bundled gems also happened. I have not been able to identify which change resulted in the new, seemingly random and intermittent failures.

Google led me here first, and second to this discussion on a minitest issue:
[https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/744](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/744#issuecomment-546251999)

Then, looking closer at my tests, I noticed that the first test to fail always triggered an async method.

I added this to my `config/environments/test.rb` file:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline
```

And all tests are passing again.

I don't know if this constitutes a fix or a work around. I'm not sure if asynchronous processes were working before or if they were previously being handled inline and a default behavior changed. The tests we currently have aren't specifically validating asynchronicity. So, for the moment, this solved my problem.

Comment: FYI— In my case I discovered also it was race conditions + Mysql. If I switched to SQLite (but still had the race conditions), the test suite did not do this. (For a while I switched to SQLite while I couldn't figure out why MySQL was giving me that). Once I cleared up the race conditions/timing problems in my test suite, however, I switched back to MySQL and these errors went away. So essentially, it was race conditions.

Comment: I have the same error message today. I discover that this message appears since I added a test with ActiveStorage attachment. All tests after this new test failed, a part with validations failures (model just created is not found in database) and other with this 'Mysql client is not connected' error.
I add your fix and all tests pass again.
But I don't really understand what is causing this errors.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had issues while running tests for ActiveJob background jobs, and
adding `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test` to config/environments/test.rb worked for me.

Comment: This is the right answer. The problem is happening because RSpec rolls back the transaction while active support tries to process attachments in the background, perhaps in a separate thread.